# Controlling NextUI Autocomplete Component doesn't work with async filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, controlled-component, nextui

I have encountered a problem with the NextUI autocomplete component. I am trying to control the selectedKey following the [docs here](https://nextui.org/docs/components/autocomplete). Controlling the component works as expected for a synchronous component. However, as soon as I introduce asynchronous filtering, controlling the component stops working. Has anyone else encountered this issue? Does anyone have any advice?

You can see the issue in action in my [codepen here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/vigilant-microservice-thncc4?workspaceId=9367cda1-b343-4621-bc73-de8b8fe6fdb1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu1d9wzf00083b6i0sp864rn%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu1d9wzf00033b6izr9z06me%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu1d9wzf00053b6inynzbzcf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu1d9wzf00073b6ig4b6iwr5%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clu1d9wzf00033b6izr9z06me%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu1d9wzf00033b6izr9z06me%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu1dfxwj004f3b6glomypwqi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A12%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A27%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A13%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A31%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FApp.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu1dfxwj004f3b6glomypwqi%2522%257D%252C%2522clu1d9wzf00073b6ig4b6iwr5%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu1d9wzf00063b6iv7mpcixe%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu1d9wzf00073b6ig4b6iwr5%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu1d9wzf00063b6iv7mpcixe%2522%257D%252C%2522clu1d9wzf00053b6inynzbzcf%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu1d9wzf00053b6inynzbzcf%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu1d9wzf00043b6i7ev1chew%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu1d9wzf00043b6i7ev1chew%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)